# How can I use WYSIWYG editor in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to integrate Wagtail CMS with my existing Django project. Other than [this basic installation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html), I made a file named `wagtail_hooks.py`. Everything's good so far, but I need to use WYSIWYG editor on Wagtail CMS. Is there a way to access models.py for Wagtail so that I can use third-party WYSIWYG editor on model level?

**MY_APP/wagtail_hooks.py**

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import Store


class StoreAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Store
    menu_label = 'Store'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'doc-full'  # change as required
    menu_order = 10  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = False  # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view
    list_display = ['id', 'status', 'typ', 'businessName',]
    search_fields = ('businessName', 'created_by__username',)


# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(StoreAdmin)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a third party WYSIWYG? The whole reason I used Wagtail for my site was that it comes built in with one that you can customize, and that it supports images.

Comment: Models that I wanna use with WYSIWYG are TextField(). Is WYSIWYG supposed to be applied automatically or should I configure something additionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wagtail comes with an excellent WYSIWYG editor, Draftail, based on DraftJS. It is highly extensible:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html

To use it, you can change your model to use `wagtail.core.fields.RichTextField` instead of `TextField`.

There are several other WYSIWYG editors available, for example, you can still use the old editor with this setting:

```
WAGTAILADMIN_RICH_TEXT_EDITORS = {
    'default': {
        'WIDGET': 'wagtail.admin.rich_text.HalloRichTextArea'
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Huh, the code snippet you included wasn't shown on mobile. Apologies if this answer doesn't apply to the `ModelAdmin` you're trying to do.